# Как сгруппировать значения со списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Дано

```
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Раз N у нас 4, то значит нужно сгруппировать значения в списке по четыре элемента.
Т.е. берем со списка первые 4 элемента и кладем их в лист, берем следующие 4 элемента и так далее...
В итоге получаем такой новый список

```
r = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практически решение @strawdog , только зачем удалять, и автоматически получится для не кратного n

```
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

r = [l[x:n+x] for x in range(0, len(l), n)] # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: а почему в последнем выражении в конце 4 не заменить на n?

Comment: Спасибо, прозевал

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант (при котором исходный список будет удален):

```
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
r = []
while l:
    r.append(l[:n])
    del l[:n]

print(r)
```

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

Если исходный список будет не кратен `n`, то результат будет такой:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13]]

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import islice

def chunks_from(size, value):
    it = iter(value)
    while True:
        chunk = list(islice(it, size))
        if chunk: yield chunk
        else: break

a = list(chunks_from(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
print(a)  # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Разбивает список на более мелкие списки указанного размера.

Используйте list() и range() для создания списка нужного размера. 
Используйте map () в списке и заполните его сращениями данного списка. 
Наконец, верните использование созданного списка.

```
from math import ceil

def chunk(lst, size):
  return list(
    map(lambda x: lst[x * size:x * size + size],
      list(range(0, ceil(len(lst) / size)))))

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 4)

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```